# How to add a mp3 handler to sox?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, mp3, sox

I want to play music in the terminal with `sox`.

```
# install sox/lame
sudo apt-get install sox
sudo apt-get install lame

# play music
play music.mp3
# play FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `mp3'

# mp3 -> wav
lame --decode music.mp3 music.wav

# play music
play music.wav
```

---

```
~ $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"

~ $ sox --version
sox: SoX v14.3.2
```

The size of `music.wav` is +10 times larger than `music.mp3`.
I don't want to convert all `*.mp3` to `*.wav`.
Is it possible to add mp3-handler to sox?

Comment: what linux distro are you on... and what version of the distro and sox are you running... also running `sox -h` reports codecs supported by the program... please check if mp3 is supported therein...

Comment: instead of the present accepted answer (lame/pipe), the correct/simplest answer is install `libsox-fmt-all` http://superuser.com/a/421168/73961

Comment: Yup, that would explain why @kev's answer has more than fifty times as many upvotes as the accepted answer. Is this a stackexchange record?! 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe?

```
lame --decode music.mp3 - | play -
```

Won't leave any trace.

Comment: The question was about a sox handler. This is definitely not sox :)

Comment: you can also pipe into sox

Comment: @Elektordi The `play` command is SoX. It's basically `sox -d`. Like `ffmpeg` vs. `ffplay`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that... My bad... :/

Answer (score 313):

Install libsox-fmt-mp3:

```
sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-mp3
```

Comment: I found I also needed to upgrade sox after that; so it doesn't hurt to add "sox" to the above command.

Comment: This does not work for me. Even after `aptitude reinstall sox` I still get a `SoX was compiled without MP3 encoding support` when I try to run `sox` afterwards. (Though admittedly I'm still running Lucid, this might work better on a more modern Ubuntu.)

Comment: @kev, you should select this as the accepted answer. Also, there is a `libsox-fmt-all` package that installs the mp3 format, as well as all other available formats.

Comment: +1, this should be the accepted answer because it allows for other things beyond playing as well, for example conversion (e.g. `sox input.wav output.mp3` won't work without this package)

Comment: after installing libsox-fmt-mp3 and running it i get a :
sox WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync

Comment: @zrajm indeed I had no problems here on Linux Mint, this answer did the trick for me

Comment: on Debian there's the libsox-fmt-all package which gives you more too!  I also did an apt-get purge sox and apt-get install sox afterward just in case, but I don't know if it was actually necessary.  Worked fine.

Comment: This works great in ubuntu 18.04

Comment: This worked for Pop!_OS 22.04: `sudo apt-get install libsox-fmt-all sox`