# How can I further lower the quality of a .mp3?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sound-editing

So I wanna have a very Bad sounding audio file for a song for meme purposes, and I can't any further compress the audio. I Just want very low quality and bad sounding audio. So yeah I don't know how to do that. I also use Ubuntu 20.04 and SoX will not work for me it just says this "sox FAIL formats: no handler for file extension `mp3'". i've tried about every audio file type with it and it just won't work. i've also done plenty or google searching and all I get is use SoX.

Comment: You want that in your question. https://superuser.com/questions/421153/how-to-add-a-mp3-handler-to-sox is useful too to work out what SoX actually supports at the very least

Answer (score 2):

Re-encode at a lower bit rate, and use constant bit-rate (CBR).

`ffmpeg` is the tool you want to use.  Try `apt-get ffmpeg` from a terminal as root.  You may also need to install `libmp3lame` or similar.

Then:

> ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -codec:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k output.mp3

Valid bit rates for MP3s are

8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 192, 224, 256, 320 kb/s

Anything under 128 is going to sound bad.  Re-encode multiple times for more aliasing and even lower quality.

Comment: Thanks, this helps quite a bit.